# time/date calculations

Tags: timezone, php

I have a database of users and each user has its own timezone settings.
For example, user A has GMT-05:00 , user B has GMT+1:00 , etc

I am trying to display the correct current date/time for this users using the simplest way I can find.  I got to this code, which although it looks good (imho), it displays a positive difference (+5 hours) instead of negative (minus 5 hours).

Script below:

```
<?php
    // below two lines -- info that I normally take from DB
    $row['callstart'] = "1362067791";  // unixtimestamp
    $userInfo['timezone'] = 'GMT-5';

    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['callstart'])."\n"; // original hour

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['callstart']);
    $date = new DateTime($date,new DateTimeZone('GMT'));

    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($userInfo['timezone']));
    $row['callstart'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $row['callstart']; // converted to GMT-5 hour
?>
```

Results below:

```
  root@ssw238:/tmp# php /work/yy.php
  2013-02-28 16:09:51 // that's the current GMT hour/date
  2013-02-28 21:09:51 // should actually be 11:09:51 instead of 21:09:51
  root@ssw238:/tmp#
```

Any idea where and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Taking a gamble and saying you are building a rating engine? Does the feed have a timezone offset as part of the specification, or are they actually sending a unixtimestamp? I ask because there may be a better way to do this (exp. 7 years in telco billing) :)

Comment: Yeah, its a CDR database (source/destination/time of call). All call times are in GMT , since customers are spread around 5-6 time zones.  The system date is in GMT, so i'm not doing any timezone offsets when inserting info into DB (check the $row['callstart']  value, its exactly 16:09:51 GMT .   What better way do you suggest? PS: yes, the softswitch is sending unix timestamp records.

Comment: Dodgy switch :) Most respectable feeds will send you a local time, and server time (or at the very least, the local time, and UTC offset). That being said - is this your insert script to the DB, or are you fetching unixtimestamp and then on-the-fly displaying the local time?

Comment: Call time == with server time. There's no way for the switch to know the customer's timezone (due to the softswitch licensing model and closed source code I cannot add this info to the accounts in the softswitch), so i can work with only calltime as unixtimestamp/GMT.  I'm fetching the call logs from SQL and need to display them for customer viewing and invoicing in their respective timezone hour/date.

Comment: Trent, although Marko D has a good answer (he's right about the posix style/reversed signs) , I wouldn't mind continuing this conversation elsewhere :) -- I added you on fb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is when common sense works against us... From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area)

`In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zone names beginning with "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed from what most people expect. In this style, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is 14 hours ahead/east of GMT.)`

So the solution is

```
// below two lines -- info that I normally take from DB
$row['callstart'] = "1362067791";  // unixtimestamp
// reversed the sign
$userInfo['timezone'] = 'GMT+5';

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['callstart'])."\n"; // original hour

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['callstart']);
$date = new DateTime($date,new DateTimeZone('GMT'));

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($userInfo['timezone']));
$row['callstart'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $row['callstart']; // converted to GMT-5 hour
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm ... i rather youse this

```
 <?php



$row['callstart'] = "1362067791";
$userInfo['timezone'] = 'GMT-5';

$orginal =date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['callstart']);
echo $orginal;
echo '<br/>';

$newdate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',($orginal + strtotime(substr($userInfo['timezone'] ,3).'hours')));
echo $newdate

?>
```

2013-02-28 17:09:51
2013-02-28 13:22:36

Comment: Hi ddjikic, Few things that I don't understand. 1: why use strtotime on a unix timestamp. 2. - why use substr on the resulted date?  == I removed the strtotime statement and ran your example, got result 1970-01-01 00:00:00 , which is not a good date